# writing a cfc with better technique

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, lucee

i have one question, i have a parent cfc created generic file and a child cfc created. now i created one method method in child cfc and used that function in the parent cfc to run my code and return me the status of true/false.

the above is working but i want it to be a better way, using a setter/getter and property tags to make it that generic so i do not have to use the child function call in parent because that is breaking the oops concept, any idea how can do it

right now i have this

parent.cfc

```
if(mychildfunction() = 100) {
    dump("yeah")
}
else {
    dump("no")
}
```

child.cfc

```
function mychildfunction() {
    return "90"
}
```

Comment: You need to include info on your cfcomponent tags. Also I don't know if you are using extends or not.

Comment: what info on the cfcomponent, an yes the child.cfc extends the parent.cfc

Comment: If the child extends the parent, you cannot call the child method from the parent component.

Comment: i think my question is not being understood, here is the gist i havehttps://trycf.com/gist/2735b2664b97d3db6d8f485ba943aa57/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: and i want to e in better oops, because mine works but its breaking laws of oops

Comment: Your Gist makes no sense. There can only be one component in a `.cfc` file.